# Facebook Recommendations Social Plugin not pulling article images

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-recommendations

On my homepage, www.womensministry.net, I have the Recommendations Social Plugin from Facebook. The Recommendations pulled, however, do not display relevant pictures from the articles. I have pulled the iframe script directly from Facebook Developers. Any help with pulling images would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you view iframe URL in another window, one of the images will show: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/recommendations.php?site=www.womensministry.net&width=620&height=300&header=true&colorscheme=light&linktarget=_parent&border_color&font=arial&appId=202359153168110

Comment: Also, if you open your page in Firefox w/ Firebug console showing, there are a few errors that might be related to this (or they might not).

Answer (score 1):

As any Facebook Social Plugin, Recommandations parse its informations from og tags on your pages.

You should read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ and add at least the following tag :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://your.image.url/here"/>
```

inside your

```
<head></head>
```